# Create and maintain multiple Ciphers

Tags: java, multithreading, encryption

I'm running into an issue where multiple threads are fighting over an RSA `javax.crypto.Cipher`, and I'm looking into keeping a collection of Ciphers - one for each thread. However `Cipher.getInstance()` gives me the same instance. Should I look into a `clone()` or is there a better way, like a `new Cipher()`? 
We've considered `synchronized{}` and just use single instance of `Cipher` but it's too slow.
Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: That should not happen. `Cipher` should create an instance of `CipherSpi` each time `getInstance()` is called. Are you using a specific cryptographic provider?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913075/to-pool-or-not-to-pool-java-crypto-service-providers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me that different threads get different `Cipher` instances -- at least under JDK 1.6.0_33 under Mac OSX.  Maybe this is because I'm using BouncyCastle provider?

Were you trying to call `getInstance()` from the same thread twice or from different threads?  `clone()` does not seem to be available for Ciphers so that is not an option.

One solution would be to use [object pools](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/ObjectPool.html) so that multiple cipher instances would be used in parallel by multiple threads.  This might not work if the the JDK returns the same cipher instance on the same thread instead of a new instance.

The following code seems to spit out different identity hashcode objects for me at least:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<Cipher> localDigest = new ThreadLocal<Cipher>(){
    @Override
    protected Cipher initialValue() {
        try {
            return Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ugly but necessary
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
    new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
}

private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Cipher cipher = localDigest.get();
        System.out.println("Got digest " + System.identityHashCode(cipher));
        ...
    }
}
```

As pointed out by @marius_neo in the comments, `ThreadLocal`s can cause memory leaks in certain situations.  See: [To Pool or not to Pool java crypto service providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913075/to-pool-or-not-to-pool-java-crypto-service-providers)

Comment: A provider can always mess up the underlying implementation of course. If they map to the same `CipherSpi` instance you would get in trouble. I've never experienced that myself, but it certainly can happen (I've implemented thread safe providers).

Comment: Cool... Maybe ThreadLocal is enough in this case, implementing this now. Thanks!

Comment: Note that using ThreadLocal variables within webapplications for sharing cipher instances will lead to memory leaks : https://plumbr.eu/blog/how-to-shoot-yourself-in-foot-with-threadlocals Avoid this by doing object pools instead : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913075/to-pool-or-not-to-pool-java-crypto-service-providers

Comment: Could you elaborate more on cryptographic providers. I am getting false for `System.out.println("Equals : " + Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding").equals(Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")));`

Comment: can I use object pooling for the cipher ?

Comment: new link for resource in @marius_neo 's comment: https://plumbr.io/blog/locked-threads/how-to-shoot-yourself-in-foot-with-threadlocals